# Symfony2 , Container Service

Tags: symfony, containers

Hello i have an error on EventSubscriber for form in sonata admin

```
 namespace OneA\AdvertBundle\Form\EventListener;

 use Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactoryInterface;
 use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
 use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAware;

    class CategoryFieldsSubscriber extends ContainerAware implements EventSubscriberInterface
    {
private $factory;
public function __construct(FormFactoryInterface $factory)
{
    $this->factory = $factory;
}

public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return array(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA => 'preSetData');
}

public function preSetData(FormEvent $event)
{
    $data = $event->getData();
    $form = $event->getForm();

    //$form->add('advert_fields', 'text');
    $advert_type = $form->get('advert_type')->getData();

    $this->getFields($form, $advert_type);
}

public function getFields($form, $advert_type)
{
    $form->add('advert_fields', 'text', array(
        'label' => 'dfjg',
    ));



    $this->container->get('one_a_advert.admin_motors_field')->getFieldsForm($form);
 }
```

}

When i call the container i have this error

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in 
To the container->get(
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to send in your constructor required container like this:

```
services:
kernel.listener.your_listener:
    class: OneA\AdvertBundle\Form\EventListener\CategoryFieldsSubscriber 
    arguments: [@factory, @service_container]
```

and use this like

```
private $container;
private $factory;
public function __construct(FormFactoryInterface $factory, $container)
{
    $this->container = $container;
    $this->factory = $factory;
}
```

Comment: Thank But i call this from a class admin to sonata admin
     

How to call container in this admin class ?

Comment: How do you send factory parameter into this class?

Comment: $factory come from $formMapper in admin class : $subscriber = new CategoryFieldsSubscriber($formMapper->getFormBuilder()->getFormFactory());

Comment: you can register you CategoryFieldsSubscriber as service and then receive that in admin class from container: `$this->container->get('your_listener')` instead of using `new` operator